# download file with PHP through varnish generating them directly on the output buffer

Tags: php, varnish

the scenario is:
Download a file that is generate directly onto `php://output` write into it.

Without varnish the behavior is the file is downloaded properly while the server writing on the buffer.

with varnish the client is waiting until the whole file is generated and then download the file.

Is there a particular configuration for varnish to accomplish the start immediatly download the file instead of waiting the full generated file?

I already try to pass the URL (Varnish rule to skip the caching mechanism) where the file is generated, but writing into the buffer it doesn't make sense, doesn it?

**EDIT**

from a perspective PHP view, It open a filestream on `php://output` and write into that stream

```
$out = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
fputcsv( $out, $whatever ); // or fwrite
```

Comment: Have you tried utilizing `flush()` to send it to varnish in chunks?

Comment: From PHP perspective, you UPLOAD the file to the browser/client through varnish, not download. Question is not clear, terms used in confusing way.

Comment: I not tried to use flush. but Anyway I have no issue without Varnish. So I am guessing is a misconfiguration of varnish that it is waiting the whole file before make it available for download. (for huge file is a issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in varnish configuration:
It is enough to do not cache that specific url (and http verbs)
something like this:

```
if ((req.url ~ "/url") && (req.url == "POST")) {
  return(pipe);
}
```